# Can't run serverless. Getting path and `No such file or directory` in output

Tags: windows, bash, hadoop-yarn, serverless

I'm on Windows 8.

I installed serverless framework with yarn. 
`yarn add global serverless`

running `serverless` command in Git Bash outputs this wierd path
`/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/../../../../../Users/tempuser/AppData/Local/Yarn/Data/global/node_modules/.bin/serverless: No such file or directory`

Tried to fix it:
removed node_modules, installed again. Does not help.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output from `which serverless`?